# Custom app.config Config Section Handler

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config, configsection

What is the correct way to pick up the list of "pages" via a class that inherits from System.Configuration.Section if I used a app.config like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="XrbSettings" type="Xrb.UI.XrbSettings,Xrb.UI" />
  </configSections>

  <XrbSettings>
    <pages>
      <add title="Google" url="http://www.google.com" />
      <add title="Yahoo" url="http://www.yahoo.com" />
    </pages>
  </XrbSettings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: You should also check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject. - [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx) - [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx) - [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx) Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

Comment: Also, if you find yourself creating configuration sections frequently, there's the [Configuration Section Designer](https://github.com/hybridview/ConfigurationSectionDesigner/wiki), a graphical Domain-Specific Language designer for designing configuration sections.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First you add a property in the class that extends Section:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("pages", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PageCollection), AddItemName = "add")]
public PageCollection Pages {
    get {
        return (PageCollection) this["pages"];
    }
}
```

Then you need to make a PageCollection class. All the examples I've seen are pretty much identical so just copy [this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/nmailserver/code/HEAD/tree/NMail/trunk/NMail/Configuration/NamedServiceCollection.cs) and rename "NamedService" to "Page".

Finally add a class that extends ObjectConfigurationElement:

```
public class PageElement : ObjectConfigurationElement {
    [ConfigurationProperty("title", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Title {
        get {
            return (string) this["title"];
        }
        set {
            this["title"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("url", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Url {
        get {
            return (string) this["url"];
        }
        set {
            this["url"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some files from a sample implementation:

- [Sample config](http://sourceforge.net/p/nmailserver/code/HEAD/tree/NMail/trunk/NMail.Server.Console/NMail.config)
- [Collection and element classes](http://sourceforge.net/p/nmailserver/code/HEAD/tree/NMail/trunk/NMail/Configuration/NamedServiceCollection.cs)
- [Config section class](http://sourceforge.net/p/nmailserver/code/HEAD/tree/NMail/trunk/NMail/Configuration/NMailConfiguration.cs)

Comment: Links have broken over time

Comment: @Hoppe if you want another sample implementation I made one here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33544322/1955317