# How to get a List<string> collection of values from app.config in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, app-config

The following example fills the **ItemsControl** with a List of **BackupDirectories** which I get from code.

**How can I change this so that I get the same information from the app.config file?**

**XAML:**

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestReadMultipler2343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="Title:"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <TextBlock 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="Backup Directories:"/>
        <ItemsControl 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding BackupDirectories}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**code-behind:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestReadMultipler2343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region ViewModelProperty: Title
        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }

            set
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region ViewModelProperty: BackupDirectories
        private List<string> _backupDirectories = new List<string>();
        public List<string> BackupDirectories
        {
            get
            {
                return _backupDirectories;
            }

            set
            {
                _backupDirectories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BackupDirectories");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Title = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("title");

            GetBackupDirectoriesInternal();
        }

        void GetBackupDirectoriesInternal()
        {
            BackupDirectories.Add(@"C:\test1");
            BackupDirectories.Add(@"C:\test2");
            BackupDirectories.Add(@"C:\test3");
            BackupDirectories.Add(@"C:\test4");
        }

        void GetBackupDirectoriesFromConfig()
        {
            //BackupDirectories = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("backupDirectories");
        }


        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

**app.config:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="title" value="Backup Tool" />
    <!--<add key="backupDirectories">
      <add value="C:\test1"/>
      <add value="C:\test2"/>
      <add value="C:\test3"/>
      <add value="C:\test4"/>
    </add>-->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: simplest solution is to use [System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection.aspx): Answered for question: [Store String Array In appSettings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10419116/155207)

Comment: take look at my new answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29487138/105445

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a ConfigurationSection with a ConfigurationElementCollection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935331/how-to-implement-a-configurationsection-with-a-configurationelementcollection)

Comment: Seems to be answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32637544/69663 as well

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can create your own custom config section in the app.config file. There are quite a [few](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx#elementcolls) [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) [around](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/CustomConfigSection.aspx) to get you started. Ultimately, you could have something like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="backupDirectories" type="TestReadMultipler2343.BackupDirectoriesSection, TestReadMultipler2343" />
  </configSections>

<backupDirectories>
   <directory location="C:\test1" />
   <directory location="C:\test2" />
   <directory location="C:\test3" />
</backupDirectories>
```

To complement Richard's answer, this is the C# you could use with his sample configuration:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestReadMultipler2343
{
    public class BackupDirectoriesSection : IConfigurationSectionHandler
    {
        public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
        {
            List<directory> myConfigObject = new List<directory>();

            foreach (XmlNode childNode in section.ChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlAttribute attrib in childNode.Attributes)
                {
                    myConfigObject.Add(new directory() { location = attrib.Value });
                }
            }
            return myConfigObject;
        }
    }

    public class directory
    {
        public string location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the backupDirectories configuration section as follows:

```
List<directory> dirs = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("backupDirectories") as List<directory>;
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or do none of the three tutorials actually show you how to have a list of elements?

Comment: @Chuu Check out the examples on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx

Comment: @Demodave you can always check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33544322/1955317 here I have provided the C# code needed to do what Richard is talking about :)

Comment: @Demodave, the C# code are in the tutorial links in my answer.

Comment: when I used the same code above, im getting the below error:
Could not load file or assembly 'namespace' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 162):

You could have them semi-colon delimited in a single value, e.g.

App.config

```
<add key="paths" value="C:\test1;C:\test2;C:\test3" />
```

C#

```
var paths = new List<string>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paths"].Split(new char[] { ';' }));
```

Comment: That is such a quick way of doing it if you don't need the overhead of a custom config section. This is good enough IMO.

Comment: that was my thinking... custom config sections are very nice and very powerful, but perhaps overkill for a simple string array.

Comment: This is the way I'd done it for a long time... today I am converting to a config section because managing my list (it is a list of pluging classes to load, which can change depending on the environment) has gotten messy with 30+ strings in it.

Comment: This solution is really good idea. Just not so good when I want to edit config - erase some of paths. Adding is not a problem.

Comment: Ugh.  Great solution, but just need to mention you have to add System.Configuration as a reference (can't just use the "using") in order to get access to ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Of course, these days I'd just used ConfigR! ;-) http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04jan15/introduction-to-configr-the-solution-to-your-application-configuration-problems

Comment: @Moose If you use a user-friendly config screen to save values to app.config, 30+ strings would not be a problem with the semicolon-delimited config value

Answer (score 37):

I love Richard Nienaber's answer, but as Chuu pointed out, it really doesn't tell *how* to accomplish what Richard is refering to as a solution.
Therefore I have chosen to provide you with the way I ended up doing this, ending with the result Richard is talking about.

### The solution

In this case I'm creating a greeting widget that needs to know which options it has to greet in. This may be an over-engineered solution to OPs question as I am also creating an container for possible future widgets.

**First I set up my collection to handle the different greetings**

```
public class GreetingWidgetCollection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public List<IGreeting> All { get { return this.Cast<IGreeting>().ToList(); } }

    public GreetingElement this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as GreetingElement;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new GreetingElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((GreetingElement)element).Greeting;
    }
}
```

**Then we create the acutal greeting element and it's interface**

(You can omit the interface, that's just the way I'm always doing it.)

```
public interface IGreeting
{
    string Greeting { get; set; }
}

public class GreetingElement : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement, IGreeting
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("greeting", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Greeting
    {
        get { return (string)this["greeting"]; }
        set { this["greeting"] = value; }
    }
}
```

**The greetingWidget property so our config understands the collection**

We define our collection `GreetingWidgetCollection` as the `ConfigurationProperty` `greetingWidget` so that we can use "greetingWidget" as our container in the resulting XML.

```
public class Widgets : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
{
    public static Widgets Widget => ConfigurationManager.GetSection("widgets") as Widgets;

    [ConfigurationProperty("greetingWidget", IsRequired = true)]
    public GreetingWidgetCollection GreetingWidget
    {
        get { return (GreetingWidgetCollection) this["greetingWidget"]; }
        set { this["greetingWidget"] = value; }
    }
}
```

**The resulting XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <widgets>
       <greetingWidget>
           <add greeting="Hej" />
           <add greeting="Goddag" />
           <add greeting="Hello" />
           ...
           <add greeting="Konnichiwa" />
           <add greeting="Namaskaar" />
       </greetingWidget>
    </widgets>
</configuration>
```

**And you would call it like this**

```
List<GreetingElement> greetings = Widgets.GreetingWidget.All;
```

Comment: Where does the GreetingWidget property go?

Comment: @Rhyous I updated my answer to clarify this. But this also greatly depends on how much you modify the code for your case :)

Comment: @Squazz I think he may have been asking where the C# `GreetingWidget` property should be defined.  I assume that is intended to be added to the `GreetingWidgetCollection` class?

Comment: @PseudoPsyche GreetingWidget is defined in the second last code stump (public GreetingWidgetCollection GreetingWidget). This is the magic that defines what we are calling it in web.config :) I deliberately chose this to have concrete and clear naming all around :)

Comment: @Rhyous, in case PseudoPsyche is right about what you were asking for,  I have now added an explanation, I don't know if that is helping making the code more clear?

Comment: @Squazz I was mentioning that because I was confused as well on that. I'm still having a problem getting it to work for me though. Every time I try to read from the collection, I get a stack overflow exception. I'm assuming the usage for this would simply be: `List<IGreeting> greetingWidgets = new GreetingWidgetCollection().GreetingWidget.All;`?  

Also, how would the `section` need to be defined in the `app.config` `configSections` node? Like this: `<section name="greetingWidget" type="WidgetApp.GreetingWidgetCollection, GreetingWidget"/>`?

Comment: @Squazz Yes, that is what I was asking. I figured it out before you responded. I got it working.

Comment: @PseudoPsyche, I never had a stack overflow exception. Sounds unrelated. Likely it is a bug in code where you are calling a property from the getter of the same property.

Comment: @Rhyous glad you got it working. Sorry that the example was not complete...

Comment: What exactly is the point of the line: `public static Widgets Widget => ConfigurationManager.GetSection("widgets") as Widgets;` ?

I always have to call it like this:

`Widgets w = new Widgets();
List<GreetingElement> = w.GreetingWidget.All`

However it always returns an empty list. Calling `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` returns what I'm expecting however.

Answer (score 34):

There's actually a very little known class in the BCL for this purpose exactly: [CommaDelimitedStringCollectionConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.commadelimitedstringcollectionconverter.aspx). It serves as a middle ground of sorts between having a `ConfigurationElementCollection` (as in Richard's answer) and parsing the string yourself (as in Adam's answer).

For example, you could write the following configuration section:

```
public class MySection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("MyStrings")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CommaDelimitedStringCollectionConverter))]
    public CommaDelimitedStringCollection MyStrings
    {
        get { return (CommaDelimitedStringCollection)base["MyStrings"]; }
    }
}
```

You could then have an app.config that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="foo" type="ConsoleApplication1.MySection, ConsoleApplication1"/>
  </configSections>
  <foo MyStrings="a,b,c,hello,world"/>
</configuration>
```

Finally, your code would look like this:

```
var section = (MySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("foo");
foreach (var s in section.MyStrings)
    Console.WriteLine(s); //for example
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would go through creating a custom section, but then have it limited to a delimited string; however it is something I hadn't seen or known of.  It is interesting idea and well documented, thanks for providing!

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem, but solved it in a different way. It might not be the best solution, but its a solution.

in app.config:

```
<add key="errorMailFirst" value="test@test.no"/>
<add key="errorMailSeond" value="krister@tets.no"/>
```

Then in my configuration wrapper class, I add a method to search keys.

```
        public List<string> SearchKeys(string searchTerm)
        {
            var keys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys;
            return keys.Cast<object>()
                       .Where(key => key.ToString().ToLower()
                       .Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()))
                       .Select(key => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key.ToString())).ToList();
        }
```

For anyone reading this, i agree that creating your own custom configuration section is cleaner, and more secure, but for small projects, where you need something quick, this might solve it.

Comment: ...aside from the fact that you can query `AppSettings.Keys` directly for string equality, why the cast to `object` followed by all the casts back to `string`?

Comment: Considering I wrote this 4 years ago, I cant remember. When I see it now the casts look unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

In App.config:

```
<add key="YOURKEY" value="a,b,c"/>
```

In C#:

```
string[] InFormOfStringArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YOURKEY"].Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
List<string> list = new List<string>(InFormOfStringArray);
```

Comment: Excellent, but I have a question, I am a bit confused on the reasoning behind putting those values into an array and then placing them into a list, when you could simply do .ToList() instead?

Answer (score 2):

Found this thread when searching for how to get a list from `appsettings.json`.

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ]
  }
}
```

There you can do it like this:

```
Configuration.GetSection("foo:bar").Get<List<string>>()
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296371/3850405

Comment: You cant really use this for the app.config though, since the app config uses xml and not json. And creating a custom json file is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the question. But I have found my own solution to this problem. 
At first, I created a method

```
    public T GetSettingsWithDictionary<T>() where T:new()
    {
        IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddXmlFile($"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location}.config", false, true).Build();

        var instance = new T();
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))
            {
                property.SetValue(instance, _configurationRoot.GetSection(typeof(T).Name).Get<Dictionary<string, string>>());
                break;
            }

        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Then I used this method to produce an instance of a class

```
var connStrs = GetSettingsWithDictionary<AuthMongoConnectionStrings>();
```

I have the next declaration of class

```
public class AuthMongoConnectionStrings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
}
```

and I store my setting in App.config

```
<configuration>    
  <AuthMongoConnectionStrings
  First="first"
  Second="second"
  Third="33" />
</configuration>
```