# How to set list of values in IIS web.config?

Tags: c#, iis, web-config

In IIS web config custom settings (appSettings), I have this

```
<add key="vals" value="one,two,three" />
```

but is there a way to change it to

```
<add key="vals">
    <value>one</value>
    <value>two</value>
    <value>three</value>
</add>
```

?

Comment: Why? You can just read from key="vals" and split the string value on commas to get all the values as individual items. Please add more context to your post. "What are you trying to accomplish?"

Comment: just cleaner code, cause then I dont need to worry about encoding commas and stuff

Comment: How is that cleaner? That makes for more clutter. And a config file is not the same as code. Again, "What are you trying to accomplish?". Where are you even using these values?

Comment: If you really need to do this you can use a custom config section with some extra work as outlined in this post: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819964/multiple-values-for-a-single-config-key/2819989). If you are trying to keep it a part of the `appSettings` section this is not possible, it only allows a key with one value.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I am sure you CANNOT do this with the default AppSettings section.

I would suggest to use either comma seprated or semi-colon separated values in such cases.

If you really want the XML structure you have shown, then you can also go for custom configuration sections.  If you want example is [here](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx/).

Answer (score 0):

You could make list like below in web.config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="users" value="usera,userb"/>
  </appSettings>
```

you can access like:

```
  string[]  usersValues = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["users"].Split(",");
```