# How to implement a ConfigurationSection with a ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I am trying to implement a custom configuration section in a project and I keep running up against exceptions that I do not understand. I am hoping someone can fill in the blanks here.

I have `App.config` that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="ServicesSection" type="RT.Core.Config.ServicesConfigurationSectionHandler, RT.Core"/>
    </configSections>
    <ServicesSection type="RT.Core.Config.ServicesSection, RT.Core">
            <Services>
                <AddService Port="6996" ReportType="File" />
                <AddService Port="7001" ReportType="Other" />
            </Services>
        </ServicesSection>
</configuration>
```

I have a `ServiceConfig` element defined like so:

```
public class ServiceConfig : ConfigurationElement
  {
    public ServiceConfig() {}

    public ServiceConfig(int port, string reportType)
    {
      Port = port;
      ReportType = reportType;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Port", DefaultValue = 0, IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public int Port 
    {
      get { return (int) this["Port"]; }
      set { this["Port"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("ReportType", DefaultValue = "File", IsRequired = true, IsKey = false)]
    public string ReportType
    {
      get { return (string) this["ReportType"]; }
      set { this["ReportType"] = value; }
    }
  }
```

And I have a `ServiceCollection` defined like so:

```
public class ServiceCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
  {
    public ServiceCollection()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ServiceCollection Constructor");
    }

    public ServiceConfig this[int index]
    {
      get { return (ServiceConfig)BaseGet(index); }
      set
      {
        if (BaseGet(index) != null)
        {
          BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }
        BaseAdd(index, value);
      }
    }

    public void Add(ServiceConfig serviceConfig)
    {
      BaseAdd(serviceConfig);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
      BaseClear();
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
      return new ServiceConfig();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
      return ((ServiceConfig) element).Port;
    }

    public void Remove(ServiceConfig serviceConfig)
    {
      BaseRemove(serviceConfig.Port);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
      BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
      BaseRemove(name);
    }
  }
```

The part I am missing is what to do for the handler. Originally, I tried to implement an `IConfigurationSectionHandler` but found two things:

1. it didn't work
2. it's deprecated.

I'm completely lost now on what to do so I can read my data from config. Any help please!

Comment: I can't get this working. I'd love to see RT.Core.Config.ServicesSection. I just get Unrecognized element 'AddService' despite using the code from the accepted answer as well.

Comment: I missed this at first too - this part: [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServiceCollection),
       AddItemName = "add",
       ClearItemsName = "clear",
       RemoveItemName = "remove")]
The AddItemName has to match so if you changed "add" to "addService" it would work

Answer (score 194, accepted):

The previous answer is correct but I'll give you all the code as well.

Your app.config should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="ServicesSection" type="RT.Core.Config.ServiceConfigurationSection, RT.Core"/>
   </configSections>
   <ServicesSection>
      <Services>
         <add Port="6996" ReportType="File" />
         <add Port="7001" ReportType="Other" />
      </Services>
   </ServicesSection>
</configuration>
```

Your `ServiceConfig` and `ServiceCollection` classes remain unchanged.

You need a new class:

```
public class ServiceConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
   [ConfigurationProperty("Services", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
   [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServiceCollection),
       AddItemName = "add",
       ClearItemsName = "clear",
       RemoveItemName = "remove")]
   public ServiceCollection Services
   {
      get
      {
         return (ServiceCollection)base["Services"];
      }
   }
}
```

And that should do the trick. To consume it you can use:

```
ServiceConfigurationSection serviceConfigSection =
   ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ServicesSection") as ServiceConfigurationSection;

ServiceConfig serviceConfig = serviceConfigSection.Services[0];
```

Comment: The `[Add|Remove|Clear]ItemName` properties on the `ConfigurationCollection` attribute aren't really necessary in this case, because "add"/"clear"/"remove" are already the default names of the XML elements.

Comment: How can I make it work so that the tags are not adds? It only seems to work if they are add. It wouldn't work if it was <Service Port="6996" ReportType="File" /> or <Service Port="7001" ReportType="Other" />

Comment: @JonathanWolfson: just change AddItemName = "add" to AddItemName = "Service"

Comment: Is this still the approach for .NET 4.5?

Comment: @crush: yes, not much changes in this dusty corner of .NET.

Answer (score 92):

If you are looking for a custom configuration section like following

```
<CustomApplicationConfig>
        <Credentials Username="itsme" Password="mypassword"/>
        <PrimaryAgent Address="10.5.64.26" Port="3560"/>
        <SecondaryAgent Address="10.5.64.7" Port="3570"/>
        <Site Id="123" />
        <Lanes>
          <Lane Id="1" PointId="north" Direction="Entry"/>
          <Lane Id="2" PointId="south" Direction="Exit"/>
        </Lanes> 
</CustomApplicationConfig>
```

then you can use my implementation of configuration section so to get started add `System.Configuration` assembly reference to your project

Look at the each nested elements I used, First one is Credentials with two attributes so lets add it first

**Credentials Element**

```
public class CredentialsConfigElement : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Username")]
        public string Username
        {
            get 
            {
                return base["Username"] as string;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Password")]
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Password"] as string;
            }
        }
    }
```

**PrimaryAgent and SecondaryAgent**

Both has the same attributes and seem like a Address to a set of servers for a primary and a failover, so you just need to create one element class for both of those like following

```
public class ServerInfoConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Address")]
        public string Address
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Address"] as string;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Port")]
        public int? Port
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Port"] as int?;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'll explain how to use two different element with one class later in this post, let us skip the SiteId as there is no difference in it. You just have to create one class same as above with one property only. let us see how to implement Lanes collection

it is splitted in two parts first you have to create an element implementation class then you have to create collection element class

**LaneConfigElement**

```
public class LaneConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Id")]
        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Id"] as string;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("PointId")]
        public string PointId
        {
            get
            {
                return base["PointId"] as string;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Direction")]
        public Direction? Direction
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Direction"] as Direction?;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Direction
    { 
        Entry,
        Exit
    }
```

you can notice that one attribute of `LanElement` is an Enumeration and if you try to use any other value in configuration which is not defined in Enumeration application will throw an `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException` on startup. Ok lets move on to Collection Definition

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(LaneConfigElement), AddItemName = "Lane", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
    public class LaneConfigCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public LaneConfigElement this[int index]
        {
            get { return (LaneConfigElement)BaseGet(index); }
            set
            {
                if (BaseGet(index) != null)
                {
                    BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }
                BaseAdd(index, value);
            }
        }

        public void Add(LaneConfigElement serviceConfig)
        {
            BaseAdd(serviceConfig);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            BaseClear();
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new LaneConfigElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((LaneConfigElement)element).Id;
        }

        public void Remove(LaneConfigElement serviceConfig)
        {
            BaseRemove(serviceConfig.Id);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            BaseRemoveAt(index);
        }

        public void Remove(String name)
        {
            BaseRemove(name);
        }

    }
```

you can notice that I have set the `AddItemName = "Lane"` you can choose whatever you like for your collection entry item, i prefer to use "add" the default one but i changed it just for the sake of this post.

Now all of our nested Elements have been implemented now we should aggregate all of those in a class which has to implement `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection`

**CustomApplicationConfigSection**

```
public class CustomApplicationConfigSection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CustomApplicationConfigSection));
        public const string SECTION_NAME = "CustomApplicationConfig";

        [ConfigurationProperty("Credentials")]
        public CredentialsConfigElement Credentials
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Credentials"] as CredentialsConfigElement;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("PrimaryAgent")]
        public ServerInfoConfigElement PrimaryAgent
        {
            get
            {
                return base["PrimaryAgent"] as ServerInfoConfigElement;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("SecondaryAgent")]
        public ServerInfoConfigElement SecondaryAgent
        {
            get
            {
                return base["SecondaryAgent"] as ServerInfoConfigElement;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Site")]
        public SiteConfigElement Site
        {
            get
            {
                return base["Site"] as SiteConfigElement;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("Lanes")]
        public LaneConfigCollection Lanes
        {
            get { return base["Lanes"] as LaneConfigCollection; }
        }
    }
```

Now you can see that we have two properties with name `PrimaryAgent` and `SecondaryAgent` both have the same type now you can easily understand why we had only one implementation class against these two element.

Before you can use this newly invented configuration section in your app.config (or web.config) you just need to tell you application that you have invented your own configuration section and give it some respect, to do so you have to add following lines in app.config (may be right after start of root  tag).

```
<configSections>
    <section name="CustomApplicationConfig" type="MyNameSpace.CustomApplicationConfigSection, MyAssemblyName" />
  </configSections>
```

**NOTE:** MyAssemblyName should be without .dll e.g. if you assembly file name is myDll.dll then use myDll instead of myDll.dll

to retrieve this configuration use following line of code any where in your application

```
CustomApplicationConfigSection config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(CustomApplicationConfigSection.SECTION_NAME) as CustomApplicationConfigSection;
```

I hope above post would help you to get started with a bit complicated kind of custom config sections.

Happy Coding :)

****Edit****
To Enable LINQ on `LaneConfigCollection` you have to implement `IEnumerable<LaneConfigElement>`

And Add following implementation of `GetEnumerator`

```
public new IEnumerator<LaneConfigElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            int count = base.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                yield return base.BaseGet(i) as LaneConfigElement;
            }
        }
```

for the people who are still confused about how yield really works read [this nice article](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/)

Two key points taken from above article are

> it doesn’t really end the method’s execution. yield return pauses the
>   method execution and the next time you call it (for the next
>   enumeration value), the method will continue to execute from the last
>   yield return call. It sounds a bit confusing I think… [(Shay Friedman)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shayf/archive/2008/06/06/give-way-to-the-yield-keyword.aspx)
>
> Yield is not a feature of the .Net runtime. It is just a C# language
>   feature which gets compiled into simple IL code by the C# compiler. [(Lars Corneliussen)](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/)

Comment: Thanks for providing a complete example, this really helps a lot!

Answer (score 46):

This is generic code for configuration collection :

```
public class GenericConfigurationElementCollection<T> :   ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<T> where T : ConfigurationElement, new()
{
    List<T> _elements = new List<T>();

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        T newElement = new T();
        _elements.Add(newElement);
        return newElement;
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return _elements.Find(e => e.Equals(element));
    }

    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _elements.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

After you have `GenericConfigurationElementCollection`, 
you can simple use it in the config section (this is an example from my Dispatcher):

```
public class  DispatcherConfigurationSection: ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("maxRetry", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = 5)]
    public int MaxRetry
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this["maxRetry"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["maxRetry"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("eventsDispatches", IsRequired = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(EventsDispatchConfigurationElement), AddItemName = "add", ClearItemsName = "clear", RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public GenericConfigurationElementCollection<EventsDispatchConfigurationElement> EventsDispatches
    {
        get { return (GenericConfigurationElementCollection<EventsDispatchConfigurationElement>)this["eventsDispatches"]; }
    }
}
```

The Config Element is config Here:

```
public class EventsDispatchConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (string) this["name"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["name"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The config file would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <dispatcherConfigurationSection>
    <eventsDispatches>
      <add name="Log" ></add>
      <add name="Notification" ></add>
      <add name="tester" ></add>
    </eventsDispatches>
  </dispatcherConfigurationSection>
```

*Hope it help !*

Comment: Cool! Was thinking about the same and found that I'm not alone. Wish MS implement that for all FCL configs

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do that with a BasicMap for the Items?  I don't want to implement Add if i can avoid it.

Answer (score 33):

An easier alternative for those who would prefer not to write all that configuration boilerplate manually...

1) Install [Nerdle.AutoConfig](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nerdle.AutoConfig/) from NuGet

2) Define your ServiceConfig type (either a concrete class or just an interface, either will do)

```
public interface IServiceConfiguration
{
    int Port { get; }
    ReportType ReportType { get; }
}
```

3) You'll need a type to hold the collection, e.g.

```
public interface IServiceCollectionConfiguration
{
    IEnumerable<IServiceConfiguration> Services { get; } 
}
```

4) Add the config section like so (note camelCase naming)

```
<configSections>
  <section name="serviceCollection" type="Nerdle.AutoConfig.Section, Nerdle.AutoConfig"/>
</configSections>

<serviceCollection>
  <services>
    <service port="6996" reportType="File" />
    <service port="7001" reportType="Other" />
  </services>
</serviceCollection>
```

5) Map with AutoConfig

```
var services = AutoConfig.Map<IServiceCollectionConfiguration>();
```

Comment: Thank God for this answer

Comment: For people who just want to get it done and not necessarily create everything from scratch, this is the real answer :)

Comment: Answers starting with "install {something}" are not very good answers

Comment: @Gh61 nothing in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer supports that opinion.  After seeing this answer and trying Nerdle.Autoconfig, I'll personally never write ConfigurationSection code again.

Answer (score 5):

Try inheriting from [ConfigurationSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx).  This [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx) by Phil Haack has an example.

Confirmed, per the documentation for [IConfigurationSectionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler.aspx):

> In .NET Framework version 2.0 and above, you must instead derive from the ConfigurationSection class to implement the related configuration section handler.