# Trying to use Parallel.ForEach on a ConfigurationElementCollection. Can't get it to work

Tags: c#, app-config, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a custom configuration section with a collection that I created using the following code that I got from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935331/how-to-implement-a-configurationsection-with-a-configurationelementcollection):

```
public class GenericConfigurationElementCollection<T> : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<T> where T : ConfigurationElement, new()
{
    List<T> _elements = new List<T>();

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        T newElement = new T();
        _elements.Add(newElement);
        return newElement;
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return _elements.Find(e => e.Equals(element));
    }

    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _elements.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I implemented my collection with a property as follows:

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("states")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(StateElement))]
    public GenericConfigurationElementCollection<StateElement> States
    {
        get
        {
            return (GenericConfigurationElementCollection<StateElement>)this["states"];
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when i am trying to loop over the collection using Parallel.ForEach as below

```
Parallel.ForEach<StateElement>(config.States.GetEnumerator(), state=> theState.StateStatus(state));
```

I get the following errors:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<States.Configuration.StateElement>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<States.Configuration.StateElement>, System.Action<States.Configuration.StateElement>)' has some invalid arguments   
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<States.Configuration.StateElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<States.Configuration.StateElement>'
```

The last one has got me stumped.  Can't convert from IEnumerator to IEnumerable?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
config.States.Cast<StateElement>()
```

instead of

```
config.States.GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: That gives me an error of "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<States.Configuration.StateElement>"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your first exception.
just use config.States that works for me
if its still doesnt work send me the code and ill be more then happy to help