# C# Stuck Creating Custom Configuration Section

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I'm trying to implement creating a custom configuration section for the first time and am getting pretty beat up.

As an example, suppose I wanted to create a custom section for storing a list of CSV files to be read in by my program - Each file, therefore having:

- A Path to the file
- A Delimiter
- A List of `CsvColumn` (another type)

Then, each `CsvColumn` could have properties such as:

- The name in the file
- It's Type

(Please ignore whether this is good to be done via config or not, this is just an example to give a hierarchy so I can learn how to do this).

So, I've created the following config file:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="CsvData" type="CSV_Loader.CsvData, CSV_Loader" />
</configSections>

<CsvData>
    <CsvFiles>
        <CsvFile Path="MyPath1" Delimiter=",">
            <CsvColumn NameInFile="Col1" Type="System.String"/>
            <CsvColumn NameInFile="Col2" Type="System.String"/>
            <CsvColumn NameInFile="Col3" Type="System.Double"/>
        </CsvFile>
        <CsvFile Path="MyPath2" Delimiter=",">
            <CsvColumn NameInFile="Col1" Type="System.String"/>
        </CsvFile>
    </CsvFiles>
</CsvData>
```

And, now I'm looking to create custom classes based upon the  example / solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284649/1693085) and am getting terribly stuck. My current code looks roughly as follows:

**CsvColumn:**

```
public class CsvColumn : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("NameInFile", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string NameInFile
    {
        get { return (string)this["NameInFile"]; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Type", IsRequired = true, DefaultValue = "")]
    public string Type
    {
        get { return (string)this["Type"]; }
    }
}
```

(FYI - I'd like to store my `Type` as an actual `Type` variable, but I set it as `String` just in case that was where my issue was)

**CsvFile:**

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CsvColumn), AddItemName = "CsvColumn", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
public class CsvFile : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Path", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)(base["Path"]); }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Delimiter", DefaultValue = ",", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Delimiter
    {
        get { return (string)(base["Delimiter"]); }
    }

    public CsvColumn this[int index]
    {
        get { return (CsvColumn)BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public void Add(CsvColumn column)
    {
        BaseAdd(column);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        BaseClear();
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new CsvColumn();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((CsvColumn)element).NameInFile;
    }

    public void Remove(CsvColumn column)
    {
        BaseRemove(column.NameInFile);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Remove(String name)
    {
        BaseRemove(name);
    }
}
```

**CsvFile Collection:**

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CsvFile), AddItemName = "CsvFile", CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap)]
public class CsvFiles : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public CsvFile this[int index]
    {
        get { return (CsvFile)BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public void Add(CsvFile file)
    {
        BaseAdd(file);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        BaseClear();
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new CsvFile();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((CsvFile)element).Path;
    }

    public void Remove(CsvFile file)
    {
        BaseRemove(file.Path);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Remove(String name)
    {
        BaseRemove(name);
    }   
}
```

**CsvData:**

```
public class CsvData : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("CsvFiles")]
    public CsvFiles CsvFiles
    {
        get { return base["CsvFiles"] as CsvFiles; }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to call it in my code as follows:

```
var csvData = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CsvData") as CsvData);
```

But I am getting a `ConfigurationException` `Unrecognized element 'CsvColumn'`.
And I can't figure out why.

My main questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there an easier (**Generic**) way to implement this that would make this process easier?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Please give the full details of the exception and not just the exception name.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, Sorry, I had it in, but then forgot to post it.... I'll add it now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happens, presumably a bug in the framework, but when you have these nested **`ConfigurationElementCollection`** instances it seems to ignore the **`AddItemName`** on the **`ConfigurationCollection`** attribute of the inner collection. You can confirm this yourself by changing your **`CsvColumn`** elements to **`add`** elements and it will deserialize properly.

Adding the following constructor to your **`CsvFile`** class should solve your issue:

```
  public CsvFile()
  {
        AddElementName = "CsvColumn";
  }
```

For your second question have you tried the Library [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Comment: IT FREAKING WORKED!!!!!! - **THANK YOU!!!!** - Truly, can't thank you enough!! - This had me going NUTS!!!

Comment: As for the second question - I'm wondering on a generic solution for dealing with Config files, not CSV files... any ideas there??

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about dealing with custom config sections generically. These days I tend to steer clear of them for my own configuration and store as JSON instead.

Comment: +1 on using JSON. Configuration sections are going away with ASP.NET Core. I've done lots and lots of nested configuration elements and I can never do them without referring to past code. They are a huge pain.