# Serialize array with Newtonsoft.Json c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have some parameters in `app.config` file of my project.
I want to do these parameters as simple as possible for customers

```
<add key="name" value="Incognito"/>
<add key="emails[0].type" value="Personal"/>
<add key="emails[0].email" value="abc@abc.com"/>
```

I need to do JSON from these parameters. 
For now I use `Dictionary`

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
{
    parameters.Add(settings.GetKey(i), settings[i]);
}
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
```

In that case I have in result:

`{ "name": "Incognito", "emails[0].type": "Personal", "emails[0].email": "abc@abc.com" }`

But I want to see usual JSON array:

`{ "name": "Incognito", "emails": [{"type": "Personal", "email": "abc@abc.com"}, {...}] }`

How can I do that? How serialize it properly? Or maybe you know a way to write data in `app.config` in human readable format?

Comment: You would need to create a Model of type : **List<emails>** with emails having two properties: **type** and **email** respectively. Then you would need to set these properties in your dictionary. Then a simple serialization would give you your result.

Comment: If you've more than a few settings in app/web.config like this which are closely related, it may be worth looking in to [creating a custom ConfigurationSection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3936194/592958)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a JSON array you'll need to use something more like an array, say perhaps an `Array` or `List` of a type which has both `type` and `email` properties.

```
public class Parameters{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class Email{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Serialising an instance of `Parameters` will get you the JSON structure you desire.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an actual answer. Please put code and more explanation on what you mean.

Comment: @RahulSharma Give me chance mate ;)

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer.

Comment: So, I need to put values in this model and then serialize? Do we have simple way to serialize app.config values to json array with using newtonsoft json?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy You would need to create a custom ConfigurationSection - see my comment on your question for an example