# C# App.Config with array or list like data

Tags: c#, config

How to have array or list like information in app.config? I want user to be able to put as many IPs as possible (or as needed). My program would just take whatever specified in app.config. How to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ip" value="x" />
    <add key="ip" value="y" />
    <add key="ip" value="z" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>



public string ip = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ip"];
```

Comment: write your own configuration section. [Here's](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx/) a start.  [This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37776/Writing-a-complex-custom-configuration-section) shows you how to loop through them

Comment: @Jonesy Or use the hassle-free `StringCollection` settings type...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a List<string> collection of values from app.config in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779117/how-to-get-a-liststring-collection-of-values-from-app-config-in-wpf)

Comment: See my answer here for a way to create your own configuration section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544322/1955317

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The easiest way would be a comma separated list in your App.config file. Of course you can write your own configuration section, but what is the point of doing that if it is just an array of strings, keep it simple.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ips" value="z,x,d,e" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

public string[] ipArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ips"].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 20):

You can set the  type of a setting in the settings designer to `StringCollection`, which allows you to create a list of strings.

[image: Screenshot]

You can later access individual values as `Properties.Settings.Default.MyCollection[x]`.

In the `app.config` file this looks as follows:

```
<setting name="MyCollection" serializeAs="Xml">
<value>
    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <string>Value1</string>
        <string>Value2</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
</value>
</setting>
```

Comment: When I try and call the setting using Properties.Settings.MyCollection[x], it says An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property? any ideas?

Comment: ahh got it, something like "StringCollection someRegKeys = new Properties.Settings().RegKeys;"

Comment: Am error in my answer. Must be `Properties.Settings.Default.xyz`.

Comment: This is a nicer way to go than using string parsing.  In the settings designer, use the '...' on the right of the Values field to edit the collection of strings.  It gets converted to XML for you.

Answer (score 12):

In App.config,

```
<add key="YOURKEY" value="a,b,c"/>
```

In C#,

STRING ARRAY:

```
string[] InFormOfStringArray = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YOURKEY"].Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

LIST :

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>(InFormOfStringArray);
```

Comment: Why not use `.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`?