# Castle Windsor: How to convert an appSettings dependency to a list or an array?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a component that depends on a list of strings:

```
// ctor
public MyComponent(IList<string> someStrings) { ... }
```

Using Castle Windsor, I'm trying to provide this dependency from the `AppSettings` section of my *app.config* file like so:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<IMyComponent>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyComponent>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue("someStrings", "SomeStrings"))
);
```

The Windsor documentation on [Inline Dependencies](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md) says:

> **appSettings and conversion**: Values in the config file are stored as text, yet the dependencies in your code may be of other types (`TimeSpan` in this example). Windsor has got you covered, and for most cases will perform the appropriate conversion for you.

1. Does this cover my case where I'd like to convert to `IList<string>`?
2. If so, what is the correct way to enter the list of strings in the *app.config* file?
3. If not, is there an extensibility point where I can specify my own conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bigger issue here is that it's not trivial to store a list of values in `appSettings`.  [This question addresses it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1779117/1698557) and the best answer is to create your own section in the settings file, which you then have to access via `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` instead of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get()`, [which is what Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue() uses](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/64bd386d5c435178a6c3fa8ec0a7d93c0707f2c3/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Registration/Dependency.cs#L69).  Looking through the rest of the `Dependency` class, it seems there's no built-in way to do this.

However, if it really is just strings that you need, you have at least two options that aren't all that bad (in my opinion).

**1. Store the strings in your App.config file using a StringCollection.**

This is just a shorter, built-in version of creating your own section in App.config.  Use the editor in Visual Studio's Project Properties page to add an application setting of type `StringCollection`.  This will make your App.config look something like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="YourApplication.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <YourApplication.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SomeStrings" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value>
          <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <string>one</string>
            <string>two</string>
            <string>three</string>
          </ArrayOfString>
        </value>
      </setting>
    </YourApplication.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then when configuring your component:

```cs
// StringCollection only implements IList, so cast, then convert
var someStrings = Properties.Settings.Default.SomeStrings.Cast<string>().ToArray();
container.Register(Component.For<IMyComponent>()
                            .ImplementedBy<MyComponent>()
                            .LifestyleTransient()
                            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<IList<string>>(someStrings)));
```

**2. Store the strings as a delimited list in `appSettings`, then manually split them.**

This is likely the simpler approach, though assumes you can figure out a delimiter for your strings (which may not always be the case).  Add the values to your App.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SomeStrings" value="one;two;three;four" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then when configuring your component:

```cs
var someStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeStrings"].Split(';');
container.Register(Component.For<IMyComponent>()
                            .ImplementedBy<MyComponent>()
                            .LifestyleTransient()
                            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<IList<string>>(someStrings)));
```

---

In either case, we're just adding a small amount of work on top of `Dependency.OnValue`, which is all `Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue` does anyways.

I think this answers your questions, but to be explicit:

1. Yes, but you're doing the conversion yourself so you can convert to anything you'd like.
2. See the linked question and [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779453/1698557), or use a `StringCollection`.
3. `Dependency.OnValue` is the extension (in my opinion), and I don't know of or see any other place where you would do it.  However, given the steps above I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer - I've gone with option 2 for now.

Comment: Actually, I think the "Yes, but" answer to my first question is a "no". While Windsor lets me (out of the box) put a TimeSpan value in appSettings, it does not let me do the same for a List<string> (or string[]) value.
I'd like to figure out where Windsor does the "deserialization" from the string value to TimeSpan and see if that can be extended to List<string>.

Comment: The convesions subsystem looks the place where the magic happens: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/subsystems.md but not much documentation for it that I can find.

Comment: For future reference: @mark-seemann has a blog post touching close to this topic: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/07/AppSettingsconventionforCastleWindsor/

Comment: Good finds.  It looks like you probably could create an `ISubDependencyResolver` like in Mark's post to do this in a more "Windsory" kind of way.