# Use Cors based on an appSettings in .Net Core

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am updating a .net 4.5.2 project to .Net core web api. Right now, the Cors is setup as below based on an appSetting value `CorsAllowAll`:

```
if ((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CorsAllowAll"] ?? "false") == "true")
{
    appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
}
else
{
    ConfigureCors(appBuilder);
}

private void ConfigureCors(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.UseCors(new CorsOptions
    {
    PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
    {
        PolicyResolver = context =>
        {
           var policy = new CorsPolicy();
           policy.Headers.Add("Content-Type");
           policy.Headers.Add("Accept");
           policy.Headers.Add("Auth-Token");
           policy.Methods.Add("GET");
           policy.Methods.Add("POST");
           policy.Methods.Add("PUT");
           policy.Methods.Add("DELETE");
           policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
           policy.PreflightMaxAge = 1728000;
           policy.AllowAnyOrigin = true;
           return Task.FromResult(policy);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

How can I achieve the same in .net core? Unfortunately, I won't be knowing the URLs of each environment. But I do know that for Local, DEV and QA environments, the appSetting `CorsAllowAll` is true. But the UAT and PROD environments it would be false.

**UPDATE**
My appSettings.json is like below:

```
"AppSettings": {
    ...
    "CorsAllowAll": true 
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ConfigureServices method, define two policies namely `CorsAllowAll` and `CorsAllowSpecific`

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsAllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin() 
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                    });                    

                options.AddPolicy("CorsAllowSpecific",
                    p => p.WithHeaders("Content-Type","Accept","Auth-Token")
                        .WithMethods("POST","PUT","DELETE")
                        .SetPreflightMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1728000))
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                    ); 
            });
```

The setting `CorsAllowAll` value can be accessed from `IConfiguration` in Startup.cs. Depending on its value, it is possible to set one of the defined policies globally in `Configure` method, before calling `app.UseMvc()`.

```
//Read value from appsettings
var corsAllowAll = Configuration["AppSettings:CorsAllowAll"] ?? "false";
app.UseCors(corsAllowAll == "true"? "CorsAllowAll" : "CorsAllowSpecific");
```

Comment: My appSettings is not at the root level. It is buried inside the element "AppSettings". I edited the question to include that..

Comment: Also, my question was not on just how to get the appSettings value. But how the appBuilder.useCors can be used based on the appSetting value? I am unable to use the `ConfigureCors` method in .net core..

Comment: Please edit the answer and use `Configuration["AppSettings:CorsAllowAll"]`. `AppSettings`.`CorsAllowAll` is null always..

Comment: @user007 Updated my answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

This method works great. **WithOrigins** accepts a **string []** so you can just split an appsettings value by `;` or something else.

appsettings.json

```
  {
  "AllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:8080;http://localhost:3000"
  }
```

startup.cs

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext dbContext, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_appSettings.AllowedOrigins))
       {
          var origins = _appSettings.AllowedOrigins.Split(";");
          app.UseCors(x => x
                    .WithOrigins(origins)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
       }
```

The main reason for this semi colon format is because it is similar to Application\Properties\launchSettings.json

```js
...
"profiles": {
        "IIS Express": {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "api/values",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        "Application": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "api/values",
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000;http://192.168.50.20:5000",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: You can also just use an array as well:

```json
{
  "AllowedOrigins": ["http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:3000"]
}
```

Comment: @Tyrrrz boy did your comment send me on a wild goose chase. Turns out you can't just `Configuration.GetValue<string[]>("AllowedOrigins")` and you have to jump through some [hoops to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329108/asp-net-core-get-json-array-using-iconfiguration).