# could not get any response from api .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to pass the data on the browser in Json format using .net core API:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable< tenMinutes>> Get(string id)
{
    var result= _context.tenmins.Where(s => s.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id) && s.m_time_stamp >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).Take(2).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

the id is the ip address when i rutn the project and put the breacpont on result,i have results in List,but when it returns nothing on browser i get Can’t reach this page,what is the reason?

Comment: What is happening exactly? There's not enough here to answer you question. If I had to guess, though, I'd say it's the periods in the IP address causing the issue. ASP.NET Core doesn't serve paths with extensions by default, because these are typically static files. Even though, this is an IP address, if looks like you're requesting a file with a `.168.12.12` extension. You'd be better served by sending the IP as a query param (i.e. `/api/values?id=192.168.12.12`) and removing the route param.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i have the result it passes the right IP format and in the code behind i have the result,the problem is i dont recive the result in browser like save as json

Comment: Still not clear. Describe *exactly* what's happening/not happening in as much detail as possible.

Comment: @ChrisPratt updated my question hope its clear

Comment: What is `a` in the code? You didn't return `result`.

Comment: @LexLi sorry wrong spelling,i changed the code

Comment: @mortezasol Chris Pratt already explained what the problem is. The request will probably be filtered by the server that hosts ASP.NET Core or the firewall before it even reaches ASP.NET Core. Why don't you use a query parameter instead?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you write me how should i change my controller to do so?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Get([FromQuery] string id )i changed ,still i dont get any result in json to save it,is there any problem with my return?

Comment: did you try to enable cors in startup.cs?

Comment: @DorLugasi how should i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475175/9615185