# Reconfigure CORS policy based on settings change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a default CORS policy being setup on `Startup.cs`. To avoid redeployment, I want the policy to use the latest allowed origins that I define in my configuration (`appsettings.json` and other sources that I configured) with this setting:

```
public class CORSSettings
{
   public List<string> AllowedDomains { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

My initial idea was to set the policy with a function that will access the latest configuration using `IOptionsSnapshot<CORSSettings>`. Something along the lines of:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy
                (
                    builder =>
                    builder
                        .SetIsOriginAllowed(/* Somehow pass usable CORSSettingsHelper.IsOriginAllowed method here */)
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .Build()
                );
```

but I couldn't find a way to inject the IOptionsSnapshot in my CORSSettingHelper. I then thought maybe I can use `IOptionsMonitor.OnChange(function)` to update the policy upon change in settings but couldn't access the policy and also couldn't find where to do that.

I thought maybe I need to register my `CORSSettingsHelper` as a Singleton/Scoped service (depending on the IOptions I use), but that also seems unclear to me how to get the options there ready to be used in the `IsOriginAllowed` method.

Almost all examples for `IOptionsMonitor` and `IOptionsSnapshot` I find use them in a `Controller` but I need this code to run in the Middleware, before requests are even made and either before any request (in the case of the snapshot) or whenever settings are changed (in the case of the monitor).

How can I get my CORS policy updated based on change in settings?

Comment: may be this [blog](https://blog.dure-sameen.dev/2019/09/dynamic-cors-policy-using-net-core.html) can help you to implement it.

Comment: Yes you can achieve that using [`Options pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1). In addition, please see the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329108/asp-net-core-get-json-array-using-iconfiguration)

Comment: As per your scenario you should load `IOptions` in the configuration like this `IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings`. [`Have a look here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456918/use-cors-based-on-an-appsettings-in-net-core)