# Get Json array from appsettings.json using ASp.net core

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here I am gong to get json Array from Appsettings.json

```
"RestrictedFunctionality": {
"UserRoleId": 2,

"RestrictedMenu": [
  {
    "name": "menu1"
  },
  {
    "name": "menu2"
  },
  {
    "name": "More",
    "subMenu": ["submenu1" ]
  }
],
"AllMenu": [
  {
    "name": "menu1"
  },
  {
    "name": "menu2"
  },
  {
    "name": "menu3"
  },
  {
    "name": "menu4",
    "subMenu": [ "submenu1", "submenu2", "submenu3", "submenu4"]
  }
]
```

Here I am getting All menus and Restricted Menus.

```
   var listOfRestrictedMenu = _restFunc.Value.RestrictedMenu;            
   var listOfallMenu = _restFunc.Value.AllMenu;
```

For getting above list I am using configuration.
I have create class

```
 public class RestrictedFunctionality
    {
        public List<Menu> RestrictedMenu { get; set; }
        public List<Menu> AllMenu { get; set; }

    }
```

Menu is a class which is have name, and sub menu

```
 public class Menu
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> subMenu { get; set; }

}
```

For the configuration I have added below code in startup

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.Configure<RestrictedFunctionality>(Configuration.GetSection("RestrictedFunctionality"));

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute());
            options.Filters.Add(new CustomActionFilter());
        });

        services.AddSession();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();          

    }
```

here When logged as a Administrator I have to get AllMenus. When I logged as Normal User. I have to get a Restricted list of Menu.  For this purpose I create a allowedMenu by remove menus from AllMenu which are in the RestrictedMenu .

The Problem is When i logged as a normal user. allowedMenu are coming properly. After that when i logged as a administrator. Same allowedMenu is coming. here I am getting some json datawhich (which are allowed before)
from app setting

Comment: where is the code where you decide which menu property to read from?

Comment: Finally I return a listofMenu. Shoud i include the return Method

Comment: I don't know if that's relevant or not, just based on your description. It's your code...I would hope you know what your code is doing. have you got some code which checks the role of the logged in user and then decides which menu to show them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Get Json Array using IConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329108/asp-net-core-get-json-array-using-iconfiguration)