# ASP.NET Core - how to inject IOptionsMonitor<T[]>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I inject `IOptionsMonitor<T[]>` into a controller?

In appsettings.json

```
{
      "MyArray": [
       {
          "Name": "Name 1",
          "SomeValue": "Value 1",
       },
       {
          "Name": "Name 2",
          "SomeValue": "Value 2",
       }
      ]
}
```

In Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddOptions();
     services.Configure<MyOptions[]>(Configuration.GetSection("MyArray"));
}
```

In HomeController

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyOptions[] myOptions;
    public HomeController(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions[]> myOptions)
    {
        this.myOptions = myOptions.CurrentValue;
    }
}
```

I'm getting 
`` Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1[MyOptions[]]' while attempting to activate 'Api.Controllers.HomeController'. `` exception.

I can access the configuration by `configuration.GetSection("MyArray").Get<MyOptions[]>()` and it works, but I would like to inject it as constructor parameter.

Comment: Create a class which represents your options, that is with one property being array of some type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Get Json Array using IConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329108/asp-net-core-get-json-array-using-iconfiguration)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - they don't inject array, but object. I saw that question before I wrote my own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a class with `MyOptions[]` as a property and the inject that class  and add the whole configuration without section.

```
public class Options
{
    public MyOptions[] MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddOptions();
     services.Configure<Options>(Configuration);
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyOptions[] myOptions;
    public HomeController(IOptionsMonitor<Options> myOptions)
    {
        this.myOptions = myOptions.CurrentValue.MyArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hoped it can be done without wrapper, but I ended-up with this solution. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, add the whole configuration works for me. :D

Answer (score 1):

Late but might be helpful for someone else, just use the

```cs
services.Configure<List<string>>(configuration.GetSection("Parrent:Array"));
```

appsettings.json example:

```json
{
   "Parent": {
       "Array": ["A", "B", "C"]
   }
}
```

Comment: Not working. What is `$"Parent:Array"` if the questioner's array is in the root of appsetting.json?

Comment: It has been a long time ago so I don't remember it exactly. I think the Parent:Array was just the naming convention of me using the "Section:Subsection". The the answer another look I gave an example for the appsetting.json.

In your case I think its just `GetSection("Array")`.