# How to map a sub-array in Options into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5, blazor-server-side

My options in `appsettings.json` look like this:

```json
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "Value1": "abc",
    "Value2": 5,
    ...
    "MaxDOP": [
      {
        "Region": "A",
        "ThreadCount": 20
      },
      {
        "Region": "B",
        "ThreadCount": 30
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

I inject it as usual:

```
services.Configure<Models.AppConfigModel>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
```

The problem for me is how to map the `MaxDOP` array so that it will maintain the up-to-date sync via `IOptionsMonitor<>`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56556397) deals with arrays in general, but in my case the `Region` attribute is unique, and I would rather like a `Dictionary<string, int>` (or possibly `Dictionary<string, MaxDopSettings>` in case I will ever have more than one non-key value there) so that I could search by the region code efficiently.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Map a dictionary

Change the signature of `MaxDOP` from list to dictionary

```
"MaxDOP": {
    "A": {
      "ThreadCount": 20
    },
    "B": {
      "ThreadCount": 30
    }
}
```

Dop class:

```
public class Dop
{
    public int ThreadCount { get; set; }
}
```

Configuring:

```
services.Configure<Dictionary<string, Dop>>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings:MaxDOP"));
```

Usage:

```
public HomeController(IOptionsMonitor<Dictionary<string, Dop>> monitor)
{
    _monitor = monitor;
    Dictionary<string, Dop> a = _monitor.CurrentValue;
}
```

[image: debug info]

---

### Solution 2: Include dictionary into main settings POCO

Change the signature of `MaxDOP` from list to dictionary:

appsettings.json:

```
"ApplicationSettings": {
    "Value1": "abc",
    "Value2": 5,
    "MaxDOP": {
      "A": {
        "ThreadCount": 20
      },
      "B": {
        "ThreadCount": 30
      }
    }
  }
```

Poco classes:

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dop> MaxDOP { get; set; }
}

public class Dop
{
    public int ThreadCount { get; set; }
}
```

Configuring:

```
services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));
```

Usage:

```
public HomeController(IOptionsMonitor<ApplicationSettings> monitor)
{
    _monitor = monitor;
    ApplicationSettings a = _monitor.CurrentValue;
}
```

[image: debug info]

Comment: An interesting solution, thanks. As I understand, this will create a second injectable, separate from my main settings POCO? I would prefer to keep them all in one place, if possible.

Comment: @RogerWolf you can include Dictionary<string, Dop> with name MaxDOP into your main settings POCO, it would work. Do you need an example?

Comment: Yep, it works! I updated the JSON schema as you suggested, changed the declaration of the property to `public Dictionary<string, MaxDopApiSettings> MaxDOP_API { get; set; }` and everything was picked up by itself, no extra injections necessary! Thanks a lot!