# In dotnet core the call to config.GetSection().Get <List<object>> will not load values into the object

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, appsettings

In my appsetting.json I have the following array of values defined.

```
"DirectoriesToMonitor": [
  {
    "DirectoryToMonitor": {
      "Directory": "c:\\temp1",
      "IncludeSubDirectories": true,
      "FileTypes": "txt",
      "ZipFiles": false,
      "NotifyOnly": true
    }
  },
  {
    "DirectoryToMonitor": {
      "Directory": "c:\\temp2",
      "FileTypes": "txt",
      "ZipFiles": false,
      "NotifyOnly": true
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to load them into a list of objects with this statement.

```
List<DirectoryToMonitor> dirs = config.GetSection("DirectoriesToMonitor").Get<List<DirectoryToMonitor>>();
```

The "dirs" list is populated with 2 objects but the properties on each of the objects are not loaded from appsettings.

I have also tried this:

```
List<DirectoryToMonitor> directories = new List<DirectoryToMonitor>();
config.Bind("DirectoriesToMonitor", directories);
```

And I am getting the same result.

```
namespace FileWatcherEmailer
{
    public class DirectoryToMonitor
    {
        public string Directory { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeSubDirectories { get; set; }
        public string FileTypes { get; set; }
        public bool ZipFiles { get; set; }
        public bool NotifyOnly { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core Get Json Array using IConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329108/asp-net-core-get-json-array-using-iconfiguration)

Comment: It does have some suggestions as to other ways I can solve this problem but I would love to know why the config.Bind statement doesn't work. I assume it is something I have done or not done. It is much more elegant to deal with a POCO than parsing the return values and populating objects from that.

Comment: This answer could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41331380/418175

Comment: The object doesn't match the JSON data. The JSON file contains an array of objects with a single property named `DirectoryToMonitor`, not an object with `Directory`, `FileTypes` etc. The `DirectoryToMonitor` string is a field name, not a type name. You need to either modify the JSON file to contain the inner properties, or create a new class with a single `DirectoryToMonitor` property holding a `DirectoryToMonitor` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the Base class to this

```cs
public class DirectoryToMonitor
{
    public string Directory { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeSubDirectories { get; set; }
    public string FileTypes { get; set; }
    public bool ZipFiles { get; set; }
    public bool NotifyOnly { get; set; }
}

public class DirectoriesToMonitor
{
    public DirectoryToMonitor DirectoryToMonitor { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<DirectoriesToMonitor> DirectoriesToMonitor { get; set; }
}
```

And finally bind `json` to `List<DirectoriesToMonitor>`

```cs
List<DirectoriesToMonitor> directories = new List<DirectoriesToMonitor>();
config.GetSection("DirectoriesToMonitor").Bind(directories);
```

Or

```cs
List<DirectoriesToMonitor> directories = new List<DirectoriesToMonitor>();
config.Bind("DirectoriesToMonitor", directories);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DirectoryToMonitor` object *doesn't* match the JSON file. That file contains an array of objects with a single property, which in turn holds properties that match the `DirectoryToMonitor` class.

The `"DirectoryToMonitor"` string in the JSON file specifies a field, not an object type. JSON doesn't have types, and any JSON deserialiser will deserialise a JSON fragment to whatever type matches its contents.

For your code to work, the JSON file should look like :

```
"DirectoriesToMonitor": [
  {
    "Directory": "c:\\temp1",
    "IncludeSubDirectories": true,
    "FileTypes": "txt",
    "ZipFiles": false,
    "NotifyOnly": true
  },{
    "Directory": "c:\\temp2",
    "FileTypes": "txt",
    "ZipFiles": false,
    "NotifyOnly": true
  }
]
```

If you want to keep the file unchanged, you need to use a new class with a single `DirectoryToMonitor` property, holding a `DirectoryToMonitor` object :

```
class DirectoryToMonitorDTO 
{
    public DirectoryToMonitor DirectoryToMonitor {get; set;}
}
```

The code would have to change to :

```
List<DirectoryToMonitor> directories =
    config.GetSection("DirectoriesToMonitor")
          .Get<List<DirectoryToMonitorDTO>>()
          .Select(dto=>dto.DirectoryToMonitor)
          .ToList();
```