# ASP.NET Core MVC - binding appsettings.json section array is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been stuck with this issue for some days now, and I have tried many similar solutions but none are working for me.

I'm trying to bind a section of my `appsettings.json` to a class and inject it. I've done it fine with other parts of my config file but using an array doesn't seem to work.

Here is a snip of my config:

```
"SharedMailBoxes": [
    {
      "ActiveDirectoryGroup": "Domain\\ADGroup",
      "MailBox": "email@domain.co.uk"
    },
    {
      "ActiveDirectoryGroup": "Domain\\ADGroup",
      "MailBox": "email@domain.co.uk"
    },
    {
      "ActiveDirectoryGroup": "Domain\\ADGroup",
      "MailBox": "email@domain.co.uk"
    }
  ],
```

My class:

```
public class MailBoxes
{
    public List<SharedMailBox> SharedMailBoxes { get; set; }
}

public class SharedMailBox
{
   public string ActiveDirectoryGroup { get; set; }
   public string MailBox { get; set; }
}
```

And my Startup:

```
// Inject SharedMailboxes
List<MailBoxes> mailBoxes = new List<MailBoxes>();
this.Configuration.GetSection("SharedMailBoxes").Bind(mailBoxes);
services.AddSingleton(mailBoxes);
```

When I access the list from my controller, the count is 3 but each one is empty.

Comment: Isn't camelCase the default for properties? And you have PascalCase in the config. Can you try using `public class SharedMailBox
{
   [JsonProperty("ActiveDirectoryGroup")]
   public string ActiveDirectoryGroup { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("MailBox")]
   public string MailBox { get; set; }
}` (if you use Newtonsoft)

Comment: Btw, this should help I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41329108/asp-net-core-get-json-array-using-iconfiguration

Comment: I managed to solve the issue. It turns out that in my Startup, I should have been using as below:
         `   MailBoxes mail = new MailBoxes();
            this.Configuration.Bind("MailBoxes", mail);
            services.AddSingleton(mail);`

Comment: Right, otherwise you had a list of a list of shared mailboxes which was not reflected in the config itself. Nonetheless, I would still recommend the Options Pattern mentioned in the accepted answer on the link.