# Imposible to read array of strings form appsettings.json in asp dot net 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, appsettings

I'm trying to read some objects from appsettings.json. The json contains this structure:

```
  ...
  "DevicePool": [
    { "device":"185.215.0.91:9082", "phonePair":["644004268", "644049008"],"enabled": "true" },
    { "device":"185.215.0.92:9083", "phonePair":["644491698", "644935005"],"enabled": "true" }    
  ]
  ...
```

And I try to read it like this:

```
public DevicePoolMgr(IConfiguration configuration, string devicePoolConfigKey)
{
    _devices = new List<DevicePoolItem>();
    _configuration = configuration;
    string adbPath = Startup.AppConfig["AppConstants:AdbPath"];
            
    var valuesSection = _configuration.GetSection(devicePoolConfigKey);
    foreach (IConfigurationSection section in valuesSection.GetChildren())
    {
         bool enabled = section.GetValue<bool>("enabled");
         if (!enabled) continue;
                
         string device = section.GetValue<string>("device");
         var phoneNumbers = section.GetValue<string[]>("phonePair");
         DevicePhonePair phonePair = new DevicePhonePair(phoneNumbers[0], phoneNumbers[1]);
                
         _devices.Add(new DevicePoolItem() {Device = device, PhonePair = phonePair, Enabled = enabled});
    }
}
```

This works, mostly. I can't get the phonePair part. Device gets its value, enabled too but phonePair is null. I have seen other people using this way to read a list of strings from appsettings. So, don't know what could be the reason.

Comment: You need to do pretty much the same you're doing for `"DevicePool"`: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41330941/3034273)

Comment: I see, it seems people were doing that but with a extension library. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this works for you? I created a class to serialize, If we know the model data

```
public class DevicePool
{
    public string device { get; set; }
    public List<string> phonePair { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public bool enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then read it like below

```
var devicePools= _configuration.GetSection("DevicePool").Get<List<DevicePool>>();
```

Comment: I'm not the OP but I struggled with this and in the end just made a new JSON file, and returned it as a string. In my case I didn't have a need to deserialize just sending to a front end as a configuration.