# Get collection from settings.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I create some config file in json format:

```
{
    "SomeCollection" : [
        {
            "Val1" : "Some string",
            "Val2" : "Some string2"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I create object with this config:

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
      .Build();
```

But how can I get list of pairs Val1 and Val2?

Comment: ```var section = config.GetSection("SomeCollection"); var val1 = section.GetValue<typeval1>("Val1");```

Comment: Ok, but in file may be n time Val1, Val2 object. You understand me?

Comment: @Igabryel use GetSection as string and deserialize using the json

Comment: Can you give me some example?

Comment: you can convert section to class direcly with : ```var section = config.GetSection("SomeCollection") as YourCustomClass;``` Define a class with dictionnary in it and you can get it. Or you can try ```JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(config.GetSection("SomeCollection").ToString());```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks. After a few experiments, I get a solution!

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
  .Build();
foreach( var en in config.GetSection("SomeCollection").GetChildren())
{
  string Val1= en["Val1"];
  string Val2= en["Val2"];
}
```

Thank for trying help!

Comment: You should use `IOptions` as suggested by HenryMigo. This is definitely *not* the recommended method (and your JSON is not correctly structured)

Answer (score 1):

This is my class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebsiteAPI.Models
{
   public class CollectionInAppSettings
   {
        public IDictionary<string,string> SomeCollection { get; set; }
   }
}
```

This is my AppSettings:

```
"CollectionInAppSettings": {
    "SomeCollection": {
        "Val1": "Some string",
        "Val2": "Some string2"
    }
}
```

This is what is in my startup.cs in the ConfigureServices Section:

```
services.Configure<CollectionInAppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CollectionInAppSettings"));
```

This is whats in a dummy HelloController:

```
    private readonly IOptions<CollectionInAppSettings> _options;

    public HelloController(IOptions<CollectionInAppSettings> options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult IsUp()
    {
        return Ok(_options.Value);
    }
```

When calling the endpoint:
`https://localhost:4010/api/hello/isup`

This is returned:
`"someCollection":{"Val1":"Some string","Val2":"Some string2"}`

Here is a link to some other solutions to this problem: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169701/how-to-extract-a-list-from-appsettings-json-in-net-core)