# Storing Datasets in a RESX file

Tags: c#, .net, resources, resx

I'm very new to resources in C# / .Net files.

I need to store a table of operational data in a resource file (`*.RESX`), and cannot figure out how to do it.

If I were to do it hardcoded in C, I'd do it like this:

```
struct {
   int inputA;
   int outputB;
} dataPoint;

dataPoint myOpsData[] = { { 0,  2000},
                          {10,  4000},
                          {20,  6300},
                          {30,  8400},
                          {40, 10620} };
```

The most straightforward in the Visual Studio 2010 editor is with Strings, but that only maps a string to a value.  If I were to do this, my dataset would look something like:

```
Name:       Value:
-----       ------
PerfData1   { 0,  2000}
PerfData2   {10,  4000}
PerfData3   {20,  6300}
PerfData4   {30,  8400}
PerfData5   {40, 10620}
```

But this format would require a lot of parsing and associated validation and error handling that just seems unnecessary.

How can I represent arrays of data-points (or even more complex data-types) in a .RESX resource file?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use a resource file for this?  Doesn't seem like it's a good fit what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @e36M3:  excellent point.  I want to change the data in the resource from time to time, and simply re-build the assembly in incorporate the new data into the program.   I want to pass this off to a non-techie, so asking them to update a database, or edit hard-coded tables in source code doesn't seem practical.  If you have a good alternative, I'd definitely consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use a ResX to embed some static data in an assembly.

With Visual Studio, you can just add the file (Add a New Item or Add an Existing Item),  change the Build Action (F4 or Properties Window) to "Embedded Resource", and you can then load it with a piece of code like this (NOTE: should be in the same assembly to avoid security issues):

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApplication1.MyFile.MyExt"))
{
   // load data from stream
}
```

I suppose here the file is MyFile.MyExt, and this file is directly added to the project root, as VS automatically adds the current project namespace - here ConsoleApplication1 - to embedded resources path.

If you are unsure about this path, I suggest you use a tool such as .NET reflector that is capable of displaying embedded resources names and data from an assembly.

This will get you a Stream instance. So you can store any kind of data provided you can load/save it from/to a Stream instance (MemoryStream, StreamReader, DataSets, .NET or Xml serialized objects, Bitmaps, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track.  I included a JSON text file in my project, and made a DataContractJsonSerializer to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely better off using an app.config file.  You can use the AppSettings section to add strings, which obviously you would need to parse (similarly as to what you're trying to do with .RESX).  However the app.config file would allow you to create custom XML sections that might fit your requirements better.  The best part about using configuration files is being able to change config data without actually having to rebuild the application.

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=45

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ConfigSections.aspx

Also, take a look at the following thread, but instead of pages you would have data points:

[Custom app.config Config Section Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758986/custom-app-config-config-section-handler)