# Cannot integrate App.config values into c# code

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2010, app-config

I am trying to use the values specified by an App.config file in a C# program in Visual Studio 2010, based on the directions specified in the "accepted answer" to this post: [Custom app.config Config Section Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758986/custom-app-config-config-section-handler)

My code file is `using System.Configuration`, and I'm trying to create the following:

```
public class ConnectionCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection {
    //code here
}

public class ConnectionElement : ObjectConfigurationElement {
    //code here
}
```

However, the error messages say that ConfigurationElementCollection, ObjectConfigurationElement and ConfigurationElement can't be found.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: c#.net in visual studio 2010

Comment: That's the development environment version, not the framework version used in your project. By default it's 4.0 for VS2010. Also, have you added a reference to System.Configuration assembly?

Comment: Yes, I added the reference to System.Configuration and it still doesn't work.  Target framework is .NET framework 4.

Comment: What is this `ObjectConfigurationElement`? The `ConfigurationElementCollection` should be fine after referencing the assembly, but I don't see any `ObjectConfigurationElement`. Only `ConfigurationElement`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I wonder if it's a version issue then.

Comment: `ObjectConfigurationElement` doesn't exist in the .Net framework. It's a custom class from here - http://sourceforge.net/p/nmailserver/code/HEAD/tree/NMail/trunk/NMail/Configuration/ObjectConfigurationElement.cs

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include a reference to the actual `System.Configuration` assembly...

1. Right click on your project name in the Solution Explorer window
2. Click Add Reference
3. Select the .NET tab
4. Highlight System.Configuration and click OK

Comment: I've done this and still didn't work.  The "using" directive did not present the error.

Comment: The `System.Configuration` namespace is used in several assemblies, not just the `System.Configuration` assembly. This means that it may be a valid namespace for some other assembly you may have a reference to.  I would double check that you do in fact have a reference to that assembly.

Comment: @La-comadreja and if you look into the References node in the Solution Explorer, do you see the "System.Configuration" there? Do you see maybe yellow warning icon next to it?

Comment: I see a reference called "System.configuration" (sic, no caps for configuration) and no warning icons.  I don't know how to find if it's a warning for another assembly.

Comment: No caps? Something is whacky there. Also see my question up: what is this `ObjectConfigurationElement`? Do you have only problem with that now, or the `ConfigurationElementCollection` too still?

Comment: I've got a problem with both.  ObjectConfigurationElement is mentioned in the post referenced in my post.

Comment: Delete the reference where the C in configuration isn't capitalized and re-add.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error message? I have a feeling that you cannot compile the source above, and the error message is not a message if an exception from runtime. I assume that the `IDE` and the IntelliSense warns you.
In general, in such cases you should first try the following:

1. Place the cursor to the class the `IDE` cannot interpret, in this case for example `ConfigurationElementCollection`. Then press `Ctrl+.`. This will offer you the right using statement you need, accept that with an enter.
2. If the first step doesn't work (such in this case), then it means that you are missing an assembly reference. In this case search MSDN, and determine the needed reference. After that in the `Solution Explorer`, under the node of your Project right click on `References` node, `Add Reference...`, then select `Assemblies` node in the upcoming `Reference Manager`, check `System.Configuration` in this case, then OK. Now go back to the first step, and you get the using with `Ctrl+.`. If you still don't get the using, then you referenced the wrong assembly.

Comment: Ctrl+ doesn't seem to load any statements.  It just seems to highlight a section of the program.

Comment: Make sure that your `Target framework:` (right click `Project`, `Properties...`) is `".NET Framework 4"` and not `".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"`.

Comment: BTW, I just checked VS 2010, .NET 4, what you mention. I only have problem with ObjectConfigurationElement. Try to start with another clean project and only the first class. Does it work?

Comment: I've done what you said @Csaba_Toth.  I still get the same problem.  No, it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should approach the problem from the reference, why is it lowercase? That's strange. Right click on that lowercase System.configuration reference item, and select Properties, and look at the path of the actual file. Where is it coming from? On my machine it's C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll, but I have Windows SDK and Debugger Kit and a lot of shebang.