# Cant get configuration section from app.config

Tags: c#, configurationsection

I want load int value that is stored in configuration section in app.Config.
This is my app.Config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MySection" type="ConsoleApplication2.MySectionSection, ConsoleApplication2" />
  </configSections>
  <MySection>
    <Add key="DefaultCapacity" value="15"/>
  </MySection>
</configuration>
```

This is my Configuration section class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public sealed class MySection
    {

        private static MySectionSection _config;

        static MySection()
        {
            _config = ((MySectionSection)(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection")));
        }

        private MySection()
        {
        }

        public static MySectionSection Config
        {
            get
            {
                return _config;
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed partial class MySectionSection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
    {

        [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("Add")]
        public AddElement Add
        {
            get
            {
                return ((AddElement)(this["Add"]));
            }
        }

        public sealed partial class AddElement : System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement
        {

            [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("key", IsRequired = true)]
            public string Key
            {
                get
                {
                    return ((string)(this["key"]));
                }
                set
                {
                    this["key"] = value;
                }
            }

            [System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute("value", IsRequired = true)]
            public long Value
            {
                get
                {
                    return ((long)(this["value"]));
                }
                set
                {
                    this["value"] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try use such code to get my cofiguration section i get exception

> System.InvalidCastException. Could not allow the object type
>   "System.Configuration.DefaultSection ' to type
>   "ConsoleApplication2.MySectionSection

```
Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var mn =(MySectionSection)cfg.GetSection("MySection"); //there is exception
```

Comment: Instead you can use this code to directly get the value right? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"];

Comment: No it must be ConfigurationSection not appSettings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom app.config Config Section Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758986/custom-app-config-config-section-handler)